# Pine table (Pine Script) taking 15-20 minutes to display on screen. How to immediately display it?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am using a Pine table in a complex DCA (Dollar cost average) strategy. I have printed all the outputs in the pine table.
The code works perfectly ,but the Pine table is displayed on the chart after 15-20 min delay , that's a huge lag.

Can anyone give suggestion to display the table immediately. The below code is how I am displaying the table. but its taking 15m to display on the chart.

How can i optimize it?

```
var table t = table.new(position.top_right, 2, 18, border_width = 1)
if (barstate.islast) and intermidiate_results           
      table.cell(t, 0, 0, "Intermidiate Results", width = 20, bgcolor = #F0E68C, 
      text_size=size.small)
      table.cell(t, 0, 1, "Deal Start Condition:", width = 20, bgcolor = #DCDCDC, 
      text_size=size.small)
      table.cell(t, 0, 2, "STATUS:", width = 20, bgcolor = #FFFFFF, text_size=size.small)
      table.cell(t, 0, 3, "PROFIT PERCENTAGE:", width = 20, bgcolor =#DCDCDC, 
      text_size=size.small)

      table.cell(t, 1, 0, "", width = 10, bgcolor =#F0E68C , text_size=size.small)
      table.cell(t, 1, 1, dsc, width = 10, bgcolor =#DCDCDC , text_size=size.small)
      table.cell(t, 1, 2, status_trade, width = 10, bgcolor = #FFFFFF, text_size=size.small)
      table.cell(t, 1, 3, tostring(profit_percentage), width = 10, bgcolor =#DCDCDC, 
      text_size=size.small)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `(barstate.islast) and intermidiate_results ` condition isn't the reason?
Remember that on ticking open market barstate.islast will be true on the close of the current bar! (that's why it might take time depending on your resolution).

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, 
yes i am sure that the (barstate.islast) and intermidiate_results condition aren't the reason because i am using 1m timeframe chart and "intermidiate_results " is just the bool input from the user.

When I am applying the same thing  within the label , its appearing as soon as the(5-6 sec delay ) program is saved.

Comment: It's hard to guess without full code. There is no known way for table not to shown up. Is the script loading while you wait? As for possible ways you can playground with calling your `table.cell` calls on a single bar with `barstate.islastconfirmedhistory` variable and then update cells text with `table.cell_set_text` inside `barstate.islast` condition.

Comment: thank you i will try this